# How to make a messagebox like JPopupMenu?

Tags: java, swing

I have an app that responds to mouse movement. When the mouse is over a particular spot a message appears. I'm currently using JPopupMenu to display the message because I want a box that is modeless and doesn't have any buttons or info other than my  message (therefore eliminating JOptionPane and JDialog). Just a strip with my stuff only. Is there a better way to get this than JPopupMenu? I feel I'm using the JPopupMenu for something it wasn't designed for and that annoys me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a...

- [`JWindow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JWindow.html) which is very much like a `JPopupMenu` - essentially undecorated frame
- Undecorated [`JFrame` or `JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setUndecorated%28boolean%29).  If you're interested in the user being able to interact with the components on the popup, these provide better functionality (as I've had focus issues with `JWindow` in the past)

Comment: Yes, JFrame I think it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use **JOptionPane**. Just pass *null* for button options:

```
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Dialog Message","Dialog Heading", JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, new Object[]{}, null);
```

Comment: It would remain decorated which may not meet the needs of the OP

Comment: Hmmmm, if he needs something which is totally undecorated then he may need to integrate undecorated jframe and then do dialog trick.

Comment: It's unclear as to what the OP actually wants entirely, but given the fact they started with a `JPopupMenu`, I'd say they are a look for an undecorated window

Comment: Yes, undecorated window is what I'm looking for I think.

Comment: @Dave, hmmm, then refer to what MadProgrammer has suggested